# CustomValidator for a Primary Key (ID) Field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to validate my ID textbox so that if that ID already exists then say a message to reenter, if it doesn't exist then populate the database. I have been using customvalidation on my other textboxes in my ASPX files but I cannot seem to figure out how to have customvalidation on my ID textbox. Any help in advance, would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. One way is to handle the validation entirely in the code-behind.

```
CustomValidator myCustomValidator = new CustomValidator();
myCustomValidator.ValidationGroup = "MyGroup";
myCustomValidator.ErrorMessage = "This ID already exists.";
```

In the code-behind you could do your verification of whether or not that ID already exists, such as a database check, maybe upon a button click. Upon finding that the ID does exist, tell the CustomValidator to fail.

```
myCustomValidator.IsValid = false;
Page.Validators.Add(myCustomValidator);
```